Apache Airflow - list all glue jobs
In Apache Airflow, I have correctly setup the connection variables in the Connections UI. and saved the following DAG code in the DAG folder.
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.glue import GlueJobHook
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from datetime import datetime

# glue job
def get_glue(**kwargs):
    hook = GlueJobHook(aws_conn_id='my_id', region_name='us-east-1')

    response = hook.get_conn().get_jobs()
    print("Table information:", response)

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(dag_id='glue_catalog_hook_example',
     default_args={'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1)},
     schedule_interval='@daily',
     catchup=False)


start = EmptyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)
end = EmptyOperator(task_id='end', dag=dag)

get_table_info = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_glue_job_info',
    python_callable=get_glue,
    dag = dag
)

start>>get_table_info>>end

my problem is I encounter this error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetJobs operation: The security token included in the request is invalid. where did I go wrong?

The error you're encountering, typically occurs in AWS when the credentials (AWS Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, or session token) are invalid or expired. You have most probably configure wrong your aws_conn_id='my_id'. The code looks fine

That was my suspect too but I have checked multiple times and even refreshed the keys.  also on the Airflow Connections tab there is no session token.

can you connect to other AWS resources?

yes, I tried using this example: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#snippet-to-create-connection-and-convert-to-uri and used the conn_id, con_type into ftp, login and password. connection was suessful,

Then most probably your credentials do not have access to GLUE. You will need to configure that directly in AWS console, or via terraform or something similar

hmm I'm not that sure, I can access glue in the portal using those credentials. Maybe I will try to ask our company for installation of AWS CLI so I can check on that side.

maybe the region is missconfigured?

yeah I was hoping that was the case. The region was correct.
